# How to set EC2 hostname programmatically (from outside the instance)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hostname

This [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html) in the docs describes how to set the hostname of an EC2 instance by logging in and running:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname webserver.mydomain.com
sudo reboot
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically from *outside* the instance? I have multiple instances that I need to do this for and logging into each one is not possible.

I'm using Boto3 but can't find the right command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) for such tasks:

> AWS Systems Manager Run Command lets you **remotely** and securely manage the configuration of your managed instances.  Run Command enables you to **automate common administrative tasks** and perform ad hoc configuration changes at scale.

This would require making your instances to be recognized by AWS Systems Manager (SSM) which requires three things:

- network connectivity to SSM service.
- SSM Agent installed and running - common official AMI (ubuntu, amazon linux, ...) already have it running and setup.
- instance role with `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` managed policy